# Extract and merge selected layers from a PSD input and generate PNG output using ImageMagic

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to figure out the ImageMagick command to generate a transparent PNG image that looks [like this](https://ik.imagekit.io/demo/img/desired-output.png?tr=f-png) using Layer 2 and Layer 3 of the input PSD file - https://ik.imagekit.io/demo/img/layout.psd.

The desired output dimension matches the input PSD dimension, i.e., 1000x1000.

### Updates

Above is just one example of desired output. I am looking for a generic way to select a few layers from the input PSD and generate a transparent PDF. So a generic command would help.

### PSD file preview

[image: PSD file preview]

It has multiple layers,

```
identify layout.psd 
layout.psd[0] PSD 1000x1000 1000x1000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 273879B 0.010u 0:00.007
layout.psd[1] PSD 1033x1039 1033x1039-14-22 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.002
layout.psd[2] PSD 304x332 304x332+83+89 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.002
layout.psd[3] PSD 329x353 329x353+14+632 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.002
layout.psd[4] PSD 329x353 329x353+624+22 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.002
layout.psd[5] PSD 329x353 329x353+565+493 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.002
```

### Layer 2 preview

[image: Layer 2]

### Layer 3 preview

[image: Layer 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recreate the flattened (first layer - number 0) in the PSD file. This can be done in Imagemagick as follows in Unix syntax:

```
convert -dispose Background layout.psd[1-3] -layers coalesce \( -clone 0-2 -flatten \) -insert 0 out.psd
```

For Window, remove the \s

**ADDITION**

Sorry I thought you wanted a PSD output. For PNG output, do the following:

```
convert -dispose Background layout.psd[1-3] -layers coalesce \
\( -clone 0 -alpha set -channel a -evaluate set 0 -clone 1-2 -flatten  \) \
-delete 0-2 out.png
```

[image]

**ADDITION 2**

Here is the way to make the output PNG have size 1000x1000, i.e., the same size as in the PSD in Unix syntax.  You have to get the dimensions of the flattened layer i.e. layer [0] from the PSD first. If I understand, you want a transparent result, so no background color.

```
dims=`convert layout.psd[0] -format "%wx%h" info:`
convert -size $dims xc:none layout.psd[2-3] -coalesce -background none -layers merge +repage layout23.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @fm242, it works. Just two small issues. One - I updated question to get a generic command. Above is just one example of desired output. I am looking for a generic way to select a few layers from the input PSD and generate a transparent PDF. So a generic command would help. Second - The output with above command is 1033x1039 and not same as input PSD i.e. 1000x1000.

Comment: What happened to your input PSD? I do not see the link any longer. Are you asking about an output PNG or PDF? Your question was about PNG. If PDF, what density do you want?

Comment: I want output in PNG. The link should be working, what error are you getting "curl -I https://ik.imagekit.io/demo/img/layout.psd" HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/vnd.adobe.photoshop
Content-Length: 273879 ....

Comment: See my ADDITION 2 in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks. All works fine except that I am not able to select layers properly using bracket notation. For example `convert -size $dims xc:none layout.psd[4-] -coalesce -background none -layers merge +repage layout23.png` shows all digits but it should only select layer 4 and onwards.

Comment: You have to specify an ending layer. Use [4--1].  The -1 means the last layer.